# Get a GPO setting using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, gpo

on a windows 8 machine, I want to read the GPO setting "Accounts: Block Microsoft accounts" which can manually be configured by going here :

`Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> "Accounts: Block Microsoft accounts"`

However i want to read the setting using a ***powershell script***

The two options I tried:

1. **Generate the HTML report using Get-GPOReport :** the local policies dont come up.
2. **Using gpresult /r :** for local group policy it says The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out.

can anyone guide me as to how I should proceed.
I am extremely new to powershell!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to generate the GPO report using the `Get-GPOReport` cmdlet and then parse the XML or HTML report to get the parameter that you need.

Comment: i tried that. but the policy that i require does not come up, even after i change its value.